# Import SQL file to DBeaver

Tags: mysql, mariadb, dbeaver

I'm using the DBeaver to handle with databases.

```
|/MariaDB-mysql
|-- /information_schema
|-- /mysql
|-- /performance_schema
|-- /autoparanaiba
```

I want to run some `.sql` file inside the `autoparanaiba` but I didn't find the `IMPORT`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Right Click  on autoparanaiba  --> Tools -- > Restore Database**

[image]